# Magento 2 get total spend so far for each customer to custom customer attribute

Tags: customer, customer-account, customer-attribute, totals, order-totals

```
public function test($setup)
{
    /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    // Add new customer attribute
    $customerSetup->addAttribute(
        Customer::ENTITY,
        'Test',
        [

            'label'                 => 'test',
            'input'                 => 'text',
            'required'              => false,
            'sort_order'            => 1000,
            'position'              => 1000,
            'visible'               => true,
            'system'                => false,
            'is_used_in_grid'       => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid'    => false,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
            'default'               => '0'
        ]
    );

    // add attribute to form
    /** @var  $attribute */
    $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'lifetime_sales');
    $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit']);
    $attribute->save();

    $setup->endSetup();
}

public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $installer = $setup;

    $installer->startSetup();

    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.1', '<')) {
        $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $installer->getTable('customer_grid_flat'),
            'Test',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'nullable' => false,
                'length' => '255',
                'comment' => 'test'
            ]
        );
    }

    $installer->endSetup();
}
```

}

This is my code and I can see test in customer section in admin which is what I wanted.
But at the moment I am not sure how to populate the current amount customers have ordered. 
I want to update the test field when customer spend and update the value.

Please can anyone guide me or give any tips to progress this.

This is an example what I want to do.
If customer A purchase a product for 10 pound that should be added to test field 
If the customer A purchase again and say the product is 119.86 pound the total should be 129.86 in test field

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a dynamically populated field in the admin grid

Take a look at the following

https://github.com/DominicWatts/CustomerInfo

So you are joining to the table rather than adding a new attribute field